# How to disable the "Delete" link while deleting an object in razor view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

i have the following table which contains an ajax.actionlink to delete an object:-

```
<tr id =  @answer.AnswersID>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => answer.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => answer.Answer_Description.description)
        </td>
        <td>

       @{ string i = "Are uou sure you want to delete " + @answer.Description.ToString() + " ?";}
         @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Answer",
        new { id = answer.AnswersID },
          new AjaxOptions
          {
              Confirm = i,
              HttpMethod = "Post",
              OnBegin = string.Format(
                       "disablelink({0})",
                       Json.Encode(answer.AnswersID)),
              OnSuccess = string.Format(
                        "deleteconfirmation3({0})",
                        Json.Encode(answer.AnswersID))
          })
        </td>
        </tr>}
```

and the following `OnBegin` & `OnSuccess` scripts:-

```
function disablelink(rid) {
    $('#' + rid).attr("disabled",true);}

function deleteconfirmation3(rid) {
    $('#' + rid).remove();
    jAlert(rid + ' Was Deleted Succsfully succsfully', 'Deletion Confirmation');}
```

What i am trying to do is to prevent the user from clicking on the delete button twice , but the `('#' + rid).attr("disabled",true);` will not prevent the user from clicking on the delete link while the system is processing the first deletion request and the "Delete" link will still be enabled.
**So how i un activate the whole table row while processing the deletion request?**

**Second question :-** how i can pass two parameters to my java script function something similat to:-

```
OnSuccess = string.Format(
                            "deleteconfirmation3({0}.{0})",
                            Json.Encode(answer.AnswersID,answer.Description))
```

as the Json.Encode only allow passing one parameter ?

BR

Comment: Your row and anchor link have the same IDs. Not good. Fix that and disable the link only. Re 2nd: `string.Format(                            "deleteconfirmation3({0}.{1})",                           Json.Encode(answer.AnswersID),Json.Encode(answer.Description))`

Comment: but how i can assign an ID for the ajax.actionlink ? and also how i can make it unique comparing to the row ID ?. BR

Comment: i tried $('#' + rid).bind('click', false);
and seems it will bind the user clicks ..

Comment: or you can use `$('#' + rid).bind('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault();});`

Comment: did you solve the question? I have tryed to answer to your question with a working solution for my problem. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

For the second question you can do in this way (look at OnComplete property)

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink(@"Show others", "ActionName", "ControllerName",
     new { param1= Model.param1, param2= Model.param2 },
      new AjaxOptions
      {
          UpdateTargetId = "idDivToUpdate",
          HttpMethod = "POST",
          InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
         OnFailure = "AjaxBoxVideoGalleryFailure('showOthersFg')",
 OnBegin = "AjaxBoxVideoGalleryBegin('paramToJqueryFunction')",
 OnComplete = string.Format("showArticlesNew(window.event ? event : null,'paramToJquery','OtherParameter',{0},1,3)", myC#Variable),
 LoadingElementDuration = 250
     },
    new { @class = "cssClassToAssign", id = "idOfMyLink" })
```

for the first question I have used the toggle workaround that works good.

```
//use that line of code both in complete and failure for ajax call
function AjaxBoxVideoGalleryFailure(idbutton) {
    $('#' + idbutton).toggle();
}
function AjaxBoxVideoGalleryBegin(idbutton) {
   $('#' + idbutton).toggle();
}
```